# Which UIViewController called popViewControllerAnimated:?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

Lets say I have 3 `UIViewControllers` A, B, C.

Now lets say I call B or C from A. Not with segues, but with instantiating them in code and pushing them to the `navigationController`.

After B or C are done, they call `popViewControllerAnimated:` and therefore return to A.

At this point I would like to access a property of either B or C, depending on which one of them actually was the last one that I used.

Is there any method or property that would give me the information if the last `UIViewController` was of type B or C?

I know I could define a protocol for B and C and set A as the `delegate`, but I was looking for something else...

Comment: `A` could hold references to `B` and `C` as ivars.  What caused you to abandon the delegation pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As inconvenient as it can be to set up every time, the delegate pattern *is* the correct way to solve this. That said, the quickest, hackiest way of getting there quickly is probably just to keep the reference to the last viewController you pushed in an instance variable or property of A, then make use of this in `-viewWillAppear:`. But making sure this property is always correct once things start getting complicated is probably more work in the end than setting up a simple delegate.

Comment: I can't quite explain it, but yesterday it seemed to me as a little overhead. It is the obvious way to go, though. Thanks.